# why my pyspark linear regression model always chooses the smallest parameters as the best model?

Tags: parameters, pyspark, linear-regression, cross-validation

I am trying to use pyspark to run a linear regression with cross validation. But there is something that I do not understand: my model always chooses the model with the smallest parameters as the best model.

I download the data from https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html. There is a data set called SLID.

[image]

It looks like this:

[image]

I delete the first column, the column sex and language. Then I delete the rows with NA in it. Then I changed the column names. In the end, the data looks like:

[image]

Then, here is my code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder

spark=SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
#please change it to your own path
df = spark.read.csv("/home/feng/Downloads/SLID.csv",header=True)
df1=df

df1=df1.select(*(col(c).cast("float").alias(c) for c in df1.columns))
df1=df1.withColumnRenamed('x2','label')
assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=['x1','y1'],
    outputCol="features")
output = assembler.transform(df1)
output1=output.select(output.label,output.features)

output2=output1.randomSplit([0.3,0.7])
training=output2[0]
testing=output2[1]

lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.01)

paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
    .addGrid(lr.maxIter, [1,2,5,10,20]) \
    .addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.05,0.1, 0.3,0.5,0.7]) \
    .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0, 0.5, 1])\
    .build()

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=lr,
                          estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,                                 
  evaluator=RegressionEvaluator(predictionCol="prediction",labelCol="label",
                               metricName="rmse"),
                      numFolds=5)  # use 3+ folds in practice


# Run cross-validation, and choose the best set of parameters.
cvModel = crossval.fit(training)

a=cvModel.bestModel.extractParamMap()
for keys,values in a.items():
    print(keys)
    print(values)
```

Then I have the result like this:

```
LinearRegression_a0560f768ad8__labelCol
label
LinearRegression_a0560f768ad8__aggregationDepth
2
LinearRegression_a0560f768ad8__epsilon
1.35
LinearRegression_a0560f768ad8__standardization
True
LinearRegression_a0560f768ad8__maxIter
1
LinearRegression_a0560f768ad8__regParam
0.1
LinearRegression_a0560f768ad8__loss
squaredError
LinearRegression_a0560f768ad8__predictionCol
prediction
LinearRegression_a0560f768ad8__solver
auto
LinearRegression_a0560f768ad8__tol
1e-06
LinearRegression_a0560f768ad8__featuresCol
features
LinearRegression_a0560f768ad8__elasticNetParam
0.0
LinearRegression_a0560f768ad8__fitIntercept
True
```

This result is an example. I have actually changed a lot of different parameter sets. You can see in paramGrid, I have three parameters which have different values: maxIter, regParam, elasticNetParam. No matter which values I choose, the algorithm just gave me the best model with the smallest parameters employed. I do not think this is correct. But I cannot figure not why.

Could anyone explain this to me, telling me where I do wrong and how to revise?